# How do I debug a kml file

Tags: debugging, kml

I am editing kml files of maps of history and science of files that already appear on http://climateviewer.org/. I am editing them in Sublime text and/or Notepad since all I am doing is editing text, deleting extended data and switching links and references from my old web site MyReadingMapped to the new site which has far better technology. You can see images of the maps I made at http://climateviewer.org/myreadingmapped/

BTW, I am not a programmer or developer of software, but rather a retired marketing communications professional who understands just enough coding to make these changes and can do some html as well.

The problem I am having is that of the 30 or so files I have edited so far 4 have a parsing error that consistently involves closing a Placemark. Yet there appears to be nothing wrong with the code. I am testing the files by uploading them to Google Earth to get the error statements. And so far I have fixed many problems but I can't seem to solve this problem. Jim Lee, ClimateViewer's creator tells me to debug them.

How do I debug them and is it something I would be able to learn without formal training?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging KML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630399/debugging-kml-file)

Comment: I already know the lines affected and they all involve an end of placemark command. And I get the same statement when I convert it to xml and use Mozilla. Yet the command was entered properly, and was not in error, and the error statement does not indicate what is wrong with the properly entered command. I have even copied three lines of the previous working placemark covering the close point, close placemark and open placemark lines and replaced the error section to be sure some hidden item between the commands would be eliminated. Still did not work even when I replaced it.

Answer (score 3):

There are several tools available to debug a KML file, which is simply an XML file that must conform to rules of the KML specification. As an XML file, all start and end tags must match. In addition, the tags are case-sensitive.

The easiest trick is using a web browser to validate it. Simply rename the KML file to an XML file (rename .kml extension to .xml) then drag the .xml file onto the open web browser. Parsing errors will be identified with row and column number.

Next, you can upload the KML file to [KML Validator](http://www.kmlvalidator.com/home.htm) to get a list of potential errors that need to be fixed or run the standalone command-line [XmlValidator](https://github.com/docjason/XmlValidate) tool.

Additional tips to fix KML files are described [here](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlBestPractice.html#KML_Validation_Tools) along with details about [KML validation](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlBestPractice.html#Validating_KML).